# Differences between AspNetUserToken and custom made JWT token in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I'm working on a small side-project API and I wanted to implement JWT authentication. I already made some API with JWT and always made custom implementation and validation.

This time, I wanted to use **Identity/Entity Framework** to go faster and to use the tools that are already made for me.

While doing the GenerateToken method and looking through the internet, I noticed that a lot of the tables created by IdentityFramework are not used. And I got interested in `AspNetUserToken`.

I noticed that instead of

```
private object GenerateToken(IdentityUser user)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ApiConfig.JwtSecretKey);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(double.Parse(ApiConfig.JwtExp)), //TODO: Try parse
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
        Audience = ApiConfig.JwtAudience,
        Issuer = ApiConfig.JwtIssuer
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

Which I used to generate a new JWT token, add the claims, issuer, audience, etc... Could maybe be replaced by this :

```
//Removes existing token
_userManager.RemoveAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "lboard", "login"); 
//Creates a new one
var newToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "lboard", "login");
//Set the new token for the user 
await _userManager.SetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "lboard", "login", newToken);
```

I would like to know what are the differences between the two methods, and if there are any benefits of using a custom implementation or if I'm better off with the IdentityFramework one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GenerateUserTokenAsync` methods is used internally by other `UserManager` methods like `GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync`, `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` and so on. [REF](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs)

In order to use more abstract `GenerateUserTokenAsync`, you must provide a token provider that actually generates the token. Since you don't have any default token providers for a JWT access token, you would still have to write the logic yourself and register your custom token provider and then you could use the `GenerateUserTokenAsync` method.

You would still need to write the JWT logic by yourself, incude claims etc, but with an added overhead.